# Selenium in Python - drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm trying to find a drop-down element so I can select an option from it, I've seen that Selenium has an inbuilt class for dealing with select drop-downs however I'm struggling to actually find the element.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**Element I'm trying to find**

```
<div>
<label>Department<font color="red"><em>*</em></font></label>
<select name="department">
<option value="XXX">Select</option>
<option value="1">Department 1</option>
<option value="2">Department 2</option>
<option value="3">Department 3</option>
</div>
```

**What I've tried**

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@label='Department']")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@name='Department']")

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@label='Department']")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Department']")
```

No joy - any chance someone call tell me where I'm going wrong?

Apologies for the basic question - new to selenium and a beginner programmer to boot.

Thanks.

Comment: The last `xpath` `"//select[@name='Department']"` should work. What happens when you try it? try adding some [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: @Guy Thanks for the quick reply. Using the last xpath just gives me a generic 
  `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable 
  to locate element: //select[@name='Department']}`

I'll try an explicit wait now!

Comment: @Guy `element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='Department']")))` Also failed to find the element.

Comment: Check if the dropdown is inside iframe.

Comment: @Guy that was it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue I was having was due to the select/drop-down being inside an `iframe`. Thank you to Guy for telling me to check for this.

To check if the element is in an `iframe` just inspect the website element and look for an encompassing `<iframe>` tag.

After some research on how to get around this, I solved my issue with the following code.

```
iframe = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='frame2']")
browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='department']")
```

Thanks again Guy!

Answer (score 0):

In your dom, two points have unique identification to find select element.

1.One select tag itself has name attribute with value as 'department'. (small case)

```
 browser.find_element_by_name("department")
```

or

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name ='department']")
```

or

```
 browser. find_element_by_css_selector("select[name='department']")
```

2.Other one is label with innerText as 'Department'(title) which is sibling of select

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text() = 'department']/following-sibling::select")
```